# TypeError from attempted exponentiation

Tags: operators, python-3.4, exponentiation

I am trying to graph as a function of r the probability for finding the electron in the ground state of the two dimensional and three-dimensional hydrogen atom. The code I have right now is:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def three_dimensional(radius):
    bohr = (5.2917721067)*10**(-11)
    use_radius = []
    for i in radius:
        new_rad = bohr*i
        use_radius.append(new_rad)

    answers = []
    for i in use_radius:
        R_r = (2//(bohr)**(3//2))*math.exp(-i/bohr)
        answers.append(R_r)

    probability = []
    for i in answers:
        probs = i^2
        probability.append(probs)

    print(answers)

    return plt.contour(answers, probability)
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You want the `**` operator, which is the exponent operator in Python, instead of `^`. So this line should be:

```
for i in answers:
    probs = i**2
    probability.append(probs)
```

Comment: oh wow, can't believe I did that! Thank you so much. Now I am having issues with my input, I am getting back this error messageTypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'

Comment: is there a better plotting function I could be using?

Comment: That would be a matter for a separate question.